# What factors determine if a comment section thrives?

Tags: html, design, comments

Most of the time, comment sections seem to be a playgrounds for arguments, insults and vulgarity.

Maybe I shouldn't put one on my website, but if I do, what factors determine if a comment section thrives?

The comment section will obviously vary enormously depending on the content of your website, but I am afraid that since my website is targeting  a non-technical large audience, there is too much room for the kind of comments we can see on 9gag or Youtube.

(I will not be able to moderate or hire someone to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't be moderating it, then don't put one there. It WILL draw in the worst of the internet.

Do what better sites do. Don't allow comments. Less than a third of all comments are beneficial and mostly in the smallest of ways.